# Visual Studio, outlining: Too easy to delete entire region

Tags: visual-studio, outlining

The #region feature is great, but I just realized you can delete an entire collapsed region by just one backspace or delete, and there's no warning dialogue like "You are about to delete a lot of your code. Are you sure?"

I know it can be brought back by undo easily, but I'm still concerned about not realizing I've accidentally deleted it and closing Visual Studio and loosing all the code.

Is there anything that can be done to satisfy my silly concerns? I've been looking in the options and also tried searching the internet but haven't found anything useful.

Comment: You can lose code to a lot of other problems as well (accidentally deleting the wrong folder, hard drive crashes, etc.). Solution: backups!
Also, use version control software (subversion, or git, ...) if you don't already.

Comment: How about "don't use regions" ?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Sorry, but that is helpful as "Turn off your computer and go play outside" ....

Comment: I realise that but the comment was partly serious, though a bit flippant. The fact that you have regions is usually a sign that you have stuff in there that for some reason, part of the time, you consider irrelevant. This is usually a sign of code structured incorrectly, like a class that does too many things, or a method that is too long. I will agree it is not really helpful and I can tell you that there is no way to configure Visual Studio to warn you about the problem you're asking about but my advice still stands. Don't use regions.